# How to ignore type while Deserialization using Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, json.net

I am trying to Deserialize json data which i have to with respect to model class i have

**Json :**

```
"{'test':'1339886'}"
```

**Classes :**

```
public class NewtonTest
    {
        public Element test { get; set; }
    }
public class Element
    {
        public string sample { get; set; }
    }
```

**In Main class :**

```
//under Main
string jsonData =  "{'test':'1339886'}";
var  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NewtonTest>(jsonData);
```

**Error Info :** //innner exception

*Could not cast or convert from System.String to Test.Element."*

I am completely aware of what the error states as i am passing `string` in my `json` where as in class i have a `class` as type(mismatch happening) .

In such cases i need to handle the error and maybe place a null if there is mismatch in output but it should not throw exception .

I tried my best reading the docs and setting options via [**settings**](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings.htm) but none seem to work .

I am using version 4.5 of Newtonsoft.Json

Comment: Than surround the code with try/catch; catch the exact exception; and do whatever you want with the object.

Comment: You might need to look into [Custom Conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8030538/how-to-implement-custom-jsonconverter-in-json-net-to-deserialize-a-list-of-base) or utilize dynamics by using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonData);` and then doing another process to convert that dynamic into a fully qualified object (NewtonTest, in your case).

Comment: dynamic wont work for me i tried as i have 4 inner loops so in real scenario  :) .

Comment: Your class structure doesn't match your JSON. Why aren't you creating a valid JSON?

Comment: How would a value of `1339886` be able to be converted to a complex object that is typeof `Element`

Comment: If your json data matches it will work correctly. var jsonData = "{\"test\": {\"sample\": \"1339886\"}}";

Comment: yes if json data matches perfectly everything will work . but there is a chance data coming in like that i should be handling it that's the case here . may be 1 out of 100 time . i should not leave it to chance , json data coming via user upload

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You *can* tell JSON.NET to ignore errors for specific members and types:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Error = (sender, args) => 
    {
        if (object.Equals(args.ErrorContext.Member, "test") && 
            args.ErrorContext.OriginalObject.GetType() == typeof(NewtonTest))
        {
            args.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
        }
    }
};

NewtonTest test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NewtonTest>(json, settings);
```

This code won't throw an exception. The `Error` handler in the settings object will get called and if the member throwing the exception is named `"test"` and belongs to `NewtonTest`, the error gets skipped over and JSON.NET keeps going.

The `ErrorContext` property also has other properties that you might want to leverage to only handle errors that you're absolutely sure you want to ignore.

Comment: works like gold dust . tough i removed the `if` condition to satisfy my model structure . i hope removing the condition doesn't cause any issue later . thanks a million :)

Comment: Is this possible using System.Text.Json?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a work around while using the badly formed json data.
Here is a simple solution that works.

```
 public static class NewtonHelpers
{
    internal class NewtonHelper
    {
        public string test { get; set; }
    }

    public static NewtonTest BuildNewton(string jsonData)
    {
        var newtonHelper = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NewtonHelper>(jsonData);

        var newtonTest = new NewtonTest { test = { sample = newtonHelper.test } };

        return newtonTest;
    }
}
```

Which can be used like

```
var testdata = "{'test':'1339886'}";
var newNewton = NewtonHelpers.BuildNewton(testdata);
```

Comment: appreciate your try . my case is a very rare case but i should be in a position to handle it rather modifying model(class )